# Method security ignored when using Jersey with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt, jersey

I'm having trouble getting Spring-Security to work with Jersey within my Spring Boot project. It seems to be something to do with the way the two are integrated but I can't figure out why...

In Jersey endpoints the Spring Security enforced authentication requirement (configured in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) works fine however **some method security annotations are ignored**. JSR-250 annotations (such as @DenyAll, @RolesAllowed, etc) seem to work if one registers the **RolesAllowedDynamicFeature feature**. However, @PreAuthorize, @PostAuthorize, @PreFilter, @PostFilter don't work.

<strike>Also, when logging in via the /login endpoint **the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is not sent**. Normally Spring security handles this and if I rewrite the endpoint with Spring MVC, I get both the XSRF-TOKEN and my own ACCESS-TOKEN (generated and sent by the endpoint itself).</strike>
(I found a workaround to this - see end of post)

Here's some code (I left out the obvious stuff like JwtUtils, general bean config, etc). Full source (not that there's much - this is a pared-down version of the real project) can be found at https://github.com/ChambreNoire/jersey-issue.

Thanks!

(I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.10.REALEASE and upgrading isn't currently an option)

application.yaml

```
spring:
  jersey:
    application-path: /resources
    servlet:
      load-on-startup: 1
    type: filter
```

JerseyConfig

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig {

    @Bean
    public ResourceConfig resourceConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {

        return new ResourceConfig()
            .property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true)
            .register((ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>) aClass -> objectMapper)
            .register(JacksonFeature.class)
            .register(HttpMethodOverrideFilter.class)
            .register(AuthResource.class)
            .register(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfigurationAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_PATTERNS;

    private final JwtTokenAuthFilter jwtTokenAuthFilter;
    private final JwtTokenAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfigurationAdapter(final JwtTokenAuthFilter jwtTokenAuthFilter, final JwtTokenAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler) {
        this.jwtTokenAuthFilter = jwtTokenAuthFilter;
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfig()).and()
            .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/login", "/login2")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/login2").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .headers()
                .xssProtection().and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self';require-trusted-types-for 'script';object-src 'none';");
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfig() {
        return request -> {
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowedOrigins(singletonList("http://localhost:9000"));
            config.setAllowedMethods(singletonList("*"));
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.setAllowedHeaders(singletonList("*"));
            config.setExposedHeaders(singletonList("Authorization"));
            config.setMaxAge(3600L);

            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

            return config;
        };
    }
}
```

JwtTokenAuthFilter

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JwtTokenAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final JwtTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    public JwtTokenAuthFilter(final UserDetailsService userDetailsService, final JwtTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp, final FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (req.getCookies() == null) {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            return;
        }

        String token = Arrays.stream(req.getCookies())
            .filter(c -> "ACCESS-TOKEN".equals(c.getName()))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Cookie::getValue)
            .orElse(null);

        if (isEmpty(token) || !jwtTokenUtils.validateJwtToken(token)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            return;
        }

        String username = jwtTokenUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(token);
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(req));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
}
```

AuthResource

```
@Singleton
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AuthResource {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    @Inject
    public AuthResource(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    public Response login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
        try {
            org.springframework.security.core.Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()
                    )
                );

            UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

            return Response.ok()
                .cookie(new NewCookie(
                    "ACCESS-TOKEN",
                    jwtTokenUtils.generateJwtToken(user),
                    "/", null, null,
                    NewCookie.DEFAULT_MAX_AGE,
                    true, true
                ))
                .build();

        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could enlighten me on why this is the case that would be most appreciated, or indeed any general comments/improvements you may have !

Cheers

**UPDATE**

It looks like adding the JWT cookie to the javax.ws.rs.core.Response is causing the issue although I'm not certain how. If I add it directly to the HttpServletResponse, the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is present in the response.

Here's the updated Jersey authentication endpoint :

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
public Response authenticateUser(@Context HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody LoginRequest request) {
    try {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()
                )
            );

        UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("ACCESS-TOKEN", jwtTokenUtils.generateJwtToken(user));
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);

        response.addCookie(cookie);       

        return Response.ok().build();

    } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: dont write custom security its bad practice, WHY have you written a JWTFilter when spring already has all functionality needed as a `resource server` to verify JWTs? please read the documentation instead of bad blogs

Comment: @Toerktumlare are you referring to Spring's OAuth2 Resource Server ? I'll look into it. However my problem with Jersey isn't linked to my JWTFilter config. I get the same problem (ignored PreAuthorize annotation etc) when using Spring's standard session tokens...

Comment: Read your last line ”any improvements” i did not try to answer your question in the first place

Comment: @Toerktumlare yeah I understood. Just wondering if you had any insights into the Jersey integration issue. If not no problem.